# Permalinks are returning blank pages for all sub-pages

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I was having an issue with my site, and thought maybe my permalinks were the problem, so I decided to re-save them to see if it would work.

Now all my sub-pages return blank when I go to them. The permalinks are working in the sense that I see the pretty URL in the navigation bar, but they return blank. I can go to the main page fine, but navigating from there is just blank pages.

Is there something I'm missing or something I can try to get them working again?

They are saved as the month and name permalink structure and I have updated my .htaccess with the given code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any errors in the PHP Error Log? Are you using any Custom Post Types? Does it still happen with the default theme? Sometimes deleting the .htaccess file and having Wordpress rebuild it will help.

Comment: That's what I did. I had Wordpress rebuild it.

Comment: No PHP errors? Did you try with the default theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (at least to my problem) is that I needed to delete my .htaccess file and re-create it using the default that Wordpress provided after I changed the permalink structure.